# inverted breve accent in math mode

Tags: math-mode, accents

Is there a math mode accent giving an [inverted breve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_breve)? I have tried `\stackrel{frown}{x}`, but the alignment and spacing are all wrong when compared to `\breve{x}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Psirus's idea:

```
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{T3}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\invbreve}{\mathalpha}{tipa}{16}

\begin{document}
$\invbreve{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

One has to load `fontenc` and specify the `T3` encoding; if `T1` is not desired, say `\usepackage[T3,OT1]{fontenc}` so as to get `OT1` as the default encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Check out tables 171, 173, 175 and 176 of »[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)«. Note that you have to load the corresponding package (given in the table caption) to make the respective command work.

Comment: Thanks; this solution works, too, but I can only accept one answer and chose egreg's answer because the resulting symbol looks better to me.

Comment: Personally, I had good success with `\wideparen` from the `MnSymbol` package (table 173).

Comment: I think your list of tables is no longer up to date.

Comment: This is a mixed bag. You'd naturally want an accent that looks the same for every single letter, no matter how wide the letter itself is.