# How can I draw a straight vertical accent (like textvbaraccent) over a symbol in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I draw a dot under a symbol in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39844/how-can-i-draw-a-dot-under-a-symbol-in-math-mode)

I'm looking for the equivalent of the `\textvbaraccent` command for the math mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38907/4427

```
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{T3}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\vbar}{\mathalpha}{tipa}{156}

\begin{document}
$\vbar{x}$
\end{document}
```

One has to consult the `tipa` package font tables to find out the right code. A useful package is `fonttable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\xfonttable{T3}{cmr}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

However, the file `t3enc.def` has the entry

```
\DeclareTextCommand\textvbaraccent{T3}[1]%
  {\tipaupperaccent{156}{#1}}                    % Vertical Bar Accent
```

that tells the number to use.

In general, this approach is superior to the use of `\text{\textvbaraccent{$x$}}` that doesn't place the accent taking care correctly of the slant as can be seen in the following picture (left my definition, right the result of `\text`)

[image]