# Accents in math mode LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, accents

I am searching for a way to write the opposite of **˘ $\breve{a}$**? (rotated at 180$^o$) Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question (found by @Max16hr)? [inverted breve accent in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38897/inverted-breve-accent-in-math-mode)

Comment: Its working, thank you everyone. Sorry I didn't look more to find it myself. Have a nice day.